# Template::populateStoreData() getting error in opencart after installing extension HTML Email Template: 4.2

Tags: php, opencart

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Template::populateStoreData() in /home/larssona/staging/landj20121029/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_model_sale_order.php on line 712

Got to admin sales 
click on a sale /order history

changed status to shipped
click notify user

then click on add history then this error is occuring

Comment: This is a premium extension for OpenCart, most premium extension developers offer support - try them. Although it slotted straight in to my 1.5.4.1 store without any issues.

Comment: Just to add - the extension uses the standard OpenCart models, have you made any edits to the sale/order model?